# Querystring issue with .Net Core url rewrite

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting

Working on an app in ASP.NET Core I am having a problem trying to rewrite a single url like:
https://localhost:44318/Details?content=My-url-to-rewrite&id=221
into
https://localhost:44318/mypage

The code I am using at the beginning of the Configure() method into Startup.cs is the following:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"^Details?content=My-url-to-rewrite&id=221", "/mypage", skipRemainingRules: true));
```

The strange thing is that if I try to rewrite the url without the querystring like the following, it works

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"^Details", "/mypage", skipRemainingRules: true));
```

And even adding the question mark to append the querystring it works, like the following

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"^Details?", "/mypage", skipRemainingRules: true));
```

But as soon as I add even a single character after the question mark the url is not rewritten and the page gets linked as usually without any error.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own Rewrite Middleware in the `Configure` function:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{   
    // ...
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
                    .Add(RedirectMyRequests);

    app.UseRewriter(options);
    // ...
}

static void RedirectMyRequests(RewriteContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

    // Because we're redirecting back to the same app, stop
    // processing if the request has already been redirected.
    // If the modified path is similar to the previous, use
    // an `if` statement to stop processing.

    // Check the request path and request QueryString.
    if (request.Path.Value.StartsWith(
            "/Details", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        request.QueryString.Value.StartsWith(
            "?content", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (request.QueryString.Value.Split('&')[1].StartsWith(
            "id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            // Change it with needed path, it is combined with
            // the request path and request QueryString.
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = "/Home/Privacy";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does the job, but it gives as a result a "redirect" instead of a "rewrite", involving use of the client and changing the original url in the browser bar. It is anyway a fine indication to manage the querystring value of the request and I will try to apply it to make it work with a proper "rewrite". Thanks very much.

Comment: See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/url-rewriting-middleware-in-asp-net-core-day-eight/ and write your logic in `ApplyRule`